# how to concatenate an array to another array which is of type where one inheriting from the other

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an ingredient.model which extends shoppingItem.model, to achieve the same parameters  as in the shopping model so as to later concatenate the ingredients array to my shopping list array . I have tried the following code but it doesn't get added to my shopping list array.

```
addIngredientsToShoppingList(ingredients:Ingredient[]){
        this.shoppingList.concat(ingredients);
        console.log(this.shoppingList.slice());
        this.shoppingListChanged.emit(this.shoppingList.slice());
    }
```

here Ingredient type is inherited from shoppingItem.model , do i have to typecast the ingredients to shoppingItem type first to get it concatenate into my shoppingList or what do i do?

Comment: do you have any error when concatinating the arrays? or what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: i did not get any error but the shopping list is not getting updated with the ingredients ,though its perfectly fine with the other shopping items when added

Comment: is there a way to cast ingredient to shoppingItem before concatenating, as i have tried ' this.shoppingList.concat(<ShoppingItem[]>ingredients); ' but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Merging Two arrays:

It takes all arrays for joining and maps the result of an assigned single element of a (the whole array), later c as item with b and the item b[i].

```
var array1 = [{ id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }],
        array2 = [{ id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" }, { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }],
        result = [array1, array2].reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, c, b[i])));

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry i did not understand the logic with mapping here

Answer (score 0):

sorry my mistake i did not assign the array list to the shopping list and thus the shopping list did not get updated

`this.shoppingList = this.shoppingList.concat(ingredients);`

Thanks for the help